# Android Studio shows "Could not generate DH keypair" when checking for update

Tags: android, android-studio

Environment: JVM 1.7.0_79 (Windows), Android Studio 2.1.3.

We switched to a new firewall which now allows to connect without specifying a proxy. I accepted two server certificates for the update servers permanently.

Now, search for updates seems to be broken. I will switch to a Java 8 JVM to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a Java 8 JVM, the error no longer appears.